# Make an screen with 3 screens inside and uisegmentedcontrol

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I am developing an app which needs an screen where actually there are 3 screens, I mean, there is a uisegmentedcontrol and, when I push in the options, the content of the screen changes.
I know how to do it but I think that there is a more correct way.
I put all of the components of the all screens in the screen , and depend on the click in the segmentecontrol I hide or not the elements, but is there a way to do it better? cleaner?
something like to have 3 screens independently, with the logic independently as well, and I load each one when I click in the segmentedcontrol?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I wrote [SDCSegmentedViewController](https://github.com/Scott90/SDCSegmentedViewController) for exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Make three different `UIView` objects.
2. Add your components as subviews of those views.
3. Show one of the three views depending on the selected segment index.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make three different UIViewController, so that each one will only contain the logic for its own view.
2. Each VC will contain a UISegmentControl with different default value.
3. When user click on UISegmentControl, you switch the UIViewControllers instead of UIViews, which makes it looks the same.

Comment: This solution seems unnecessarily complex.  Won't it require duplicating all the code for the segmented control (titles/images, layout, etc.) in 3 different view controllers?  Why not just use 3 different views in 1 controller?